# Integrating the OSGi Activator in GWT

Tags: gwt, osgi

I am developing a GWT Web application and I would like to integrate it within the Equinox OSGi container. In the application I have integrated the client/server packages and the Activator class into the server package. This Activator is quite simple with a single line in the start method printing a line (System.out.println). However, this line is never printed. I know the solution of OSGi declarative services in GWT, but the design of the whole platform is done by events, therefore, I need to access to the BundleContext and EventAdmin in the OSGi framework. For such purpose, I should implement the Activator class.  However, it does not work... Coudl you help me, please?

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using Spring Dynamic Modules and the injection of dependencies (IoD) feature provided by the framework. Now it gets the EventAdmin instance at the starting point and I can use the OSGi events for the communication from the GWT interface to the business logic.

Answer (score 1):

well, you can access BundleContext and EventAdmin using declarative services(DS) too... if you know that solution go ahead.

But if you activator is not being called means that you don't activate the bundle or you don't create a proper manifest.